# How to prove a no specific relation is antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $R$ and $S$ be two partial orders on a set $X$, and $T$ is a relation on $X$ such that $aTb$(i.e. $a,b$ ∊ X) if and only if both $aRb$ and $aSb$ hold. Is $T$ also a partial order on $X$?

Attempt

I know I need to prove T is reflective, antisymmetric, and transitive. I succeeded to prove T is reflective and transitive but have no idea about how to prove T is antisymmetric.
I only know $aTb$ and $bTa$ hold where $a=b$, also $aSb$ and $bSa$.

I suppose there are $aTb$ and $bTa$, but with the proofs I have now, I cannot get $a=b$ when $aTb$ and $bTa$ hold. What should I do next?

Comment: Suppose $aTb$ with $a\neq b$.  Then in particular we know this means that $aRb$ and $aSb$.  Since $R$ is a partial order, this directly implies that $bRa$ is false... which then implies something about $T$

Comment: Antisymmetry can be rephrased as "If $aRb$ and $a\neq b$ then $bRa$ is false."  This can be an easier form to work with.

Comment: I understand it. I was afraid to make two assumptions at the same time before @JMoravitz